# How to make copies (new instances) of a closure function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object/function/closure (I think it's all three?) and I need to apply separate instances of it to multiple elements on the page.

```
var NS = NS || {};
NS.PLAJAX = function(){

   var pub = {};
   var self = this;


   pub.Init = function(FormRef){      
     // do stuff
   };   

   self.aPrivateFunction = function(){      
      // do stuff
   }

   return pub;
}();


// Apply a *copy* to each element with the given class
$(function(){
   $('.el-form-wrapper').each(function(index, Element){
      // Attempt #1
       NS.PLAJAX.Init(Element); // Doesn't make copies! 

      //OR, Attempt #2      
      var Newbie = new NS.PLAJAX(); // Throws a "not a constructor" error
      Newbie.Init(Element);
   });
});
```

How can I get a new instance of this closure/object on each element?

Answer (score 2):

What you've got is just an object.  However, to use the `new` keyword, you want a function (a constructor).

There is no need to return anything from a constructor.  The `new` keyword creates a new object, calls the function with that new object as `this`, and then returns it.  Public methods should be assigned to properties of `this` (`self`) and private methods should be local variables.  What you'll end up with is something like this:

```
var NS = NS || {};
NS.PLAJAX = function(){
   var self = this;


   self.Init = function(FormRef){      
     // do stuff
   };   

   var aPrivateFunction = function(){      
      // do stuff
   }
};


// Apply a *copy* to each element with the given class
$(function(){
   $('.el-form-wrapper').each(function(index, Element){   
      var Newbie = new NS.PLAJAX();
      Newbie.Init(Element);
   });
});
```

Comment: But if you do it that way, `PLAJAX` isn't a closure anymore.

Comment: @Nick: A closure is still created that encloses the function `aPrivateFunction` within each instance of PLAJAX. Why do you think it's not a closure? What do you think closures are?

Comment: I think I was confusing closure with self-executing functions like `function DoSomething(){}();`

Comment: @Nick PLAJAX is a constructor. Notice that it creates a new closure everytime it got run inside `each` statement

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this and it works for me     hope this will work for u

```
var NS = NS || {};

NS.PLAJAX = function(){

   var pub = {};
   var self = this;


   pub.Init = function(FormRef){      
     alert(FormRef);
   };   

   self.aPrivateFunction = function(){      
      alert("private");
   }

   return pub;
};
```

// access the object NS

```
   $(function(){
  $('.el-form-wrapper').each(function(index, Element){
       var a=NS.PLAJAX();
       console.log(typeof(a));
       a.Init("gg"); // Doesn't make copies! 

          //OR, Attempt #2      
          var Newbie = new NS.PLAJAX(); // Throws a "not a constructor" error
          Newbie.Init("ff");
});
      });
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/v3G78/)**